# No gradients provided for any variable tensorflow 2.0

Tags: image, tensorflow, caption

## what this error is all about?

I am using Tensorflow 2.0, and while running the code, I am receiving this error. I am coding image caption generator.

```
def create_model():

  inputs1 = Input(shape=(4096,))
  fe1 = Dropout(0.8)(inputs1)
  fe3 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
  inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
  se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
  se2 = Dropout(0.8)(se1)
  se4 = LSTM(256)(se2)
  decoder1 = add([fe3, se4])
  decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
  outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
  model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
  model.layers[2].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
  model.layers[2].trainable = False

  return model

model = create_model()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(train_gen, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1, validation_data=dev_gen, validation_steps=dev_steps, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
```

ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:541 train_step  **
    self.trainable_variables)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1804 _minimize
    trainable_variables))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
    filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
    ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0', 'lstm_1/lstm_cell_1/kernel:0', 'lstm_1/lstm_cell_1/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_1/lstm_cell_1/bias:0', 'dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0', 'dense_5/kernel:0', 'dense_5/bias:0'].
```

Comment: You get this error when you pass only the training data and missed to pass the labels in `model.fit()`. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62077923/14290681).